# Refresh data on Mat table after Form Submission

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ui-router

I've to refresh mat table after form submission. I do it using table by following below steps.
Service

```
refreshList(){
    this.http.get(this.rootURL+'/PaymentDetail').toPromise().then(res => this.list = res as PaymentDetail[]);
    }
```

Then I call it on ngOnInit and inside Submit function on payment-detail-component.ts(component for Submit Form) and payment-detail-list.component.ts(I'm showing table here).

View of payment details.

```
<div class="jumbtron">
    <h1 class="display-4 text-center">Payment Detail Register</h1>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <app-payment-detail></app-payment-detail>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <app-payment-detail-list></app-payment-detail-list>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Following this process while I'm using Mat Table isn't works. Why mat table don't refreshed in this way? How could I refresh data in Mat Table after form submission in this structure?

Answer (score 0):

for refreshing data in material data table, you need to assign new data to dataSource object

```
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any[]>(newData);
```

you can see the example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-data-refreshsourcedata)

Comment: To show data into mat table I've defined dataSource into *payment-detail-list* component. But I've to refresh it from another component named *payment-detail*. I've to recrate dataSource into *payment-detail* component?